# net/html parses document, returns nil *html.Node no matter what

Tags: html, parsing, go

I'm trying to process an html document. Thing is that `golang.org/x/net/html`'s `Parse` returns a `*html.Node` with `nil` value, `err` is also nil, which is kind of strange because if things aren't processed by `Parse` correctly, I should get an error!

This is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "golang.org/x/net/html"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    html, err := ioutil.ReadFile("html/simple_01.html")
    if e != nil {
        fmt.Fatal(e)
    }
    doc, err := html.Parse(bytes.NewReader(html))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    // locate <body>
    var body *html.Node
    for s := doc.NextSibling; s != nil; s = s.NextSibling {
        if s.Data == "body" {
            body = s
            break
        }
    }
    log.Println(body)
}
```

`log.Println(body)` prints `nil`. Also printing `doc` prints `nil`, which is weird.

Here is the HTML document I'm testing against

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>Sample page - 01</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Aspernatur vel molestiae eius sed sunt doloremque. Ipsa sed voluptate expedita tempore id. Ab nobis delectus magnam.</p>
    <p>Beatae id mollitia nesciunt nesciunt qui explicabo cum. Aspernatur est molestiae laudantium assumenda consequuntur. Odit mollitia non inventore iusto. Id nihil voluptatem vitae. Fugit odio dolores atque sed.</p>
    <p>Qui dolorem ipsum fugit vitae consequuntur suscipit debitis iste. Dignissimos impedit nobis quas facilis. Quia dignissimos perspiciatis quia debitis. Rerum beatae repellat architecto nostrum nulla facere rerum.</p>
    <p>Quas natus ad qui excepturi dolorem. Quas dolorum dolores voluptatem distinctio quisquam culpa et. Ipsam voluptatem suscipit earum reprehenderit. Quos laudantium occaecati quis similique. Numquam rerum sunt rerum et necessitatibus. Laboriosam modi iure praesentium voluptates atque adipisci et.</p>
    <p>Blanditiis dolores nemo quos voluptatem quo quia modi. Quia et alias nesciunt sint voluptatum omnis. Nihil minima ipsa magnam qui amet ea. Blanditiis laborum nihil tempora aliquam.</p>
    <p>Ullam molestiae omnis magni ratione exercitationem minima. Sed sequi fugiat laborum omnis voluptas. Debitis sit expedita optio et at qui.</p>
    <p>Fuga iusto quo eum sequi eum sint pariatur ipsam. Alias nisi maiores illum est ab culpa voluptas quidem. Veritatis eum qui deserunt aspernatur quo officia et ipsam.</p>
    <p>Aliquam id autem earum autem eaque. Dolores veniam animi voluptatem. Et est nam culpa consequatur et ex distinctio. Quis iure sequi maiores quibusdam vel nostrum architecto et. Quisquam unde qui pariatur doloremque rerum.</p>
    <p>Dicta est est fugit et architecto. Quia culpa vel error deleniti. Voluptatem fuga omnis eius ea et voluptatum dolor.</p>
    <p>Eaque esse sint voluptatem praesentium ut sit. Fugiat ratione enim doloremque dolor asperiores. Tempora eveniet et aut.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your first error handling, you use `e` instead of `err`. Also, what do you get when you print out `html` output from reading file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several typos in your code example, but the main problem is, that you are trying to get the next sibling of the root node. You first need to get to the html tag and from there you go down to the first child and then loop through its siblings:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "golang.org/x/net/html"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    htmlfile, err := ioutil.ReadFile("html/simple_01.html")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    doc, err := html.Parse(bytes.NewReader(htmlfile))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var htmlTag = doc.FirstChild.NextSibling
    var body *html.Node
    for s := htmlTag.FirstChild; s != nil; s = s.NextSibling {
        if s.Data == "body" {
            body = s
            break
        }
    }
    log.Println(body)
}
```

Comment: Typos happen when you paste all relevant code from different files into one file 

Comment: happens to the best of us :-)